# Problem to connect teradata by odbc linux driver

Tags: linux, centos, odbc, teradata

Hello i'm trying to connect to teradata by odbc linux driver, but i have a mistake:

**[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified**

**More info:**

the driver is : **tdodbc1620-16.20.00.127-1.noarch.rpm**

**odbcinst -j**

```
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /etc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**odbcinst -q -d**

`[Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20]`

**odbcinst -q -s**

```
[ODBC]
[Teradata_ODBC_DSN}
```

**cat /etc/odbc.ini**

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
Teradata_ODBC_DSN=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20

[Teradata_ODBC_DSN]
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
DBCName=Ip
UID=
PWD=
```

**cat /etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20]
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
CPTimeout=240
```

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

```
:/usr/lib64/:/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/
```

**ODBCINI**

```
/etc/odbc.ini
```

When i execute
**isql -v Teradata_ODBC_DSN**  (get the error)

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver 
specified
```

I don't understand why the datasource not found, let's see if anyone can give me any clues, thanks

Comment: `isql` can be picky. Move the options `-v` to the end of the line

Comment: thanks, but it's the same -v at the end as at the beginning

Comment: Is your isql 32-bit? Do you have an isql64?

Comment: hello, with isql64 --> command not found, how can I download it?